# How to iterate a 4 by 4 NumPy matrix class?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I’m trying to come up with a model that optimises the expected goals figure in a football match. I have divided the match into 4 time portions. The initial probabilities for the two teams (T1 and T2) to score or not score a goal is given and remain the same in each time portions. The assumption is only one goal can be scored per time portion. For each time portion I need to process and build a distribution matrix for the score (T1, T2 or No goal) up to the end of the time portion. The matrices above (v^0 and v^1) shows the change from time portion 0, the given probability at the start of the match, and v^1 the distribution from the start to end of time portion 1( v^1).
The resulting probabilities will be used to compare the odds given at the start of the match by a betting co.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Score': ['Goal 0', 'Goal 1', 'Goal 2', 'Goal 3'],
             'Goal 0': [0.97,0.02,0,0], 'Goal 1': [0.01,0,0,0], 
             'Goal 2': [0,0,0,0], 'Goal 3': [0,0,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Score', 'Goal 0', 'Goal 1', 'Goal 2', 'Goal 3']) 
v = df.drop('Score', axis=1).as_matrix()
```

At the end of the first time portion, my matrix should look like the following,

```
v^1 = ([0.9409, 0.0097, 0.0001, 0],
             [0.0194, 0.0005, 0, 0],
             [0.0004, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And here is the code I used but for no avail.

```
def sweep(v_1):
    for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
v_tmp = np.zeros_like(v_K)

                if i == 0: v_tmp[i,j] = v_k[i, j-1] * 0.02
                if j == 0: v_tmp[i,j] = v_k[i-1, j] * 0.01
            else:
                v_tmp[i,j] = (v_k[i-1, j]) * 0.02 + (v_k[i, j]) * 0.97 + (v_k[i, j-1]) * 0.01  

    for i in range(4):
        sweep(v_1)
```

Comment: @MPA I really hope I will get it this time. Thank you for your patience sir.

Comment: In your example above, when `i == 0` and `j == 0`, you request `j-1 = -1` and `i-1 = -1` (i.e. you have negative indices). This is probably not what you intended, so what should the code be doing when `i == 0` and `j == 0`?

Comment: For the first row only, i == 0, each cell is updated by v_tmp[i,j] = v_k[i, j-1] * 0.02. similarly for first column. otherwise the 'else' algorism. Except for v_tmp[0,0], it should take the power of the order of time portion.

Comment: What does happen?  Error? Bad values?

Comment: In your `else` line of code, could you verify that `v_k[i,j-1]*0.97` is correct? It seems like a bad thing that symmetry is broken here.

Comment: @hpaulj at the end of the first time portion, the matrix should look like v^1 in the post. my code isn't giving me that. mainly i could figure out how to integrate the v_k[0,0] in my function.

Comment: @MPA you are right. It should be v_k[i,j]*0.97.

Comment: When I perform the computations in the way you describe, I get `v_tmp[1,1] = 5e-4`, and not `0.941` like you indicated above in `v^1`. Could you verify that the value of the 2nd row, 2nd column of `v^1` is correct? Otherwise there is a flaw in your explanation, or in my interpretation of that...

Comment: @MPA i can only apologise for my one too many errors. you are right it should be 0.0005.

Comment: I saw your expected value (with a screwy variable name `v^1`).  But without running your code myself, I don't know what it does produce.  Most of us are too lazy to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not my finest piece of work, but this should do what you described:

```
import numpy as np

def sweep(v_k, k):

    v_tmp = np.zeros_like(v_k)

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            if i == 0 and j == 0:
                v_tmp[i,j] = v_k[i,j]**(k+1)
            elif i == 0 and j > 0:
                v_tmp[i,j] = v_k[i,j-1]*0.02
            elif j == 0 and i > 0:
                v_tmp[i,j] = v_k[i-1,j]*0.01
            elif i > 0 and j > 0:
                v_tmp[i,j] = v_k[i-1,j]*0.02 + v_k[i,j]*0.97 + v_k[i,j-1]*0.01

    return v_tmp

v_k = np.array([
    [0.97, 0.02, 0, 0],
    [0.01, 0.00, 0, 0],
    [0.00, 0.00, 0, 0],
    [0.00, 0.00, 0, 0]
    ])

for k in range(3):
    v_k[:,:] = sweep(v_k, k)[:,:]

print(v_k)
```

Result:

```
[[8.32972005e-01 1.88180000e-02 3.88000000e-04 7.76000000e-06]
 [9.40900000e-03 1.42590000e-03 3.00700000e-05 2.90000000e-07]
 [9.70000000e-05 3.10400000e-05 3.70000000e-07 0.00000000e+00]
 [9.70000000e-07 2.30000000e-07 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]
```

Note that the result is transposed with respect to your "expected" outcome. You can try it yourself by doing `for k in range(1)` instead of `3`.

Comment: Google is your friend